# Laravel Class BaseController not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm newbie in laravel. So I've created TestController.php file, inside file:

```
<?php
class TestController extends BaseController {
public function testFunction()
{
    return "It works";
}
}
```

In routes:

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@testFunction');
```

I'm got this error:

> FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 2:
>   Class 'BaseController' not found

I'm using laravel 5, I'm trying to change from BaseController to Controller, not works :( What's wrong here? Thanks in advance :(

P.S I'm tried change to "\BaseController". Not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `BaseController` in Laravel, use `Controller` instead. `BaseController` is used once throughout the framework, in the `Controller` class, but only as a use as alias:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;  // <<< See here - no real class, only an alias
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Your controller needs this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller 
{
    public function testFunction()
    {
        return "It works";
    }
}
```

Is your TestController in app/Http/Controllers?

[image]

Comment: Ok now i'm got this error: `ReflectionException in compiled.php line 1070:
Class App\Http\Controllers\TestController does not exist`

Comment: Have you run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: true thing, you didn't namespace it. Wait one sec, I'll edit it in @Evaldas888

Comment: Hah thanks, but now i'm get: `Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script`

Comment: true again, that's why I added it to the very top @Evaldas888

Comment: Did you name your application other than App ? @Evaldas888

Comment: Ohh, and please follow  @Dave suggestion and run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled` in your projects root dir

Comment: Where is the file located? @Evaldas888

Comment: Weird. What's the error message you get now? @Evaldas888

Comment: `FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 1:
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script`

Comment: hmm i'm resaved my project in UTF-8 without bom and it works (happy)

Comment: Did you copy the code from here right? Maybe there's some sort of invisible character inside the script or whatever. Please try to delete everything above class (mark it with the cursor and delete) and write it again

Comment: Great! Good to hear, that would have been weird... @Evaldas888